# Angular CLI 7: Sass Warning while compile

Tags: angular, sass, typescript3.0

I updated the packages to latest version **7.2.1**. After Updating i got this Issue.
So any one can suggest me to fix the warning message.

> WARNING in ./src/styles.scss (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--14-3!./src/styles.scss)
>   Module Warning (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
>   Warning

Comment: Have you tried to use : npm rebuild node-sass

Comment: @NenadRadak yes i tried but it's not working still showing the same warning message.